# Higher-kinded type constructors with and without '_'

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types

This signature declares higher-kinded type:

```
case class MyContainer[A, M[_]](el: M[A])
```

Now, I can create instance of it:

```
scala> val mc1 = MyContainer[Int, Option](Some(3))
mc1: MyContainer[Int,Option] = MyContainer(Some(3))
```

I can also declare `MyContainer` as:

```
case class MyContainer[A, M[A]](el: M[A])
```

which produces same instance as `mc1`:

```
mc1: MyContainer[Int,Option] = MyContainer(Some(3))
```

What is the difference between these approaches and which should be used when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the language specification (*§4.4 Type Parameters*), these are equivalent:

> ```
> [M[X], N[X]]
> [M[_], N[_]] // equivalent to previous clause
> ```

This paragraph describes the reasoning behind this syntax:

> Higher-order type parameters (the type parameters of a type parameter `t`) are only visible in their immediately surrounding parameter clause (possibly including clauses at a deeper nesting level) and in the bounds of `t`. Therefore, their names must only be pairwise different from the names of other visible parameters. Since the names of higher-order type parameters are thus often irrelevant, they may be denoted with a `_`, which is nowhere visible.

Note that the `A` in `M[A]` is ignored in this case. It could be `T` and it would work as well:

```
scala> case class MyContainer[A, M[T]](el: M[A])
defined class MyContainer

scala> val mc1 = MyContainer[Int, Option](Some(3))
mc1: MyContainer[Int,Option] = MyContainer(Some(3))
```

To prevent confusion I would always use `[_]`, or at least not reuse the names.

Comment: It's not ignored. Try this `case class MyContainer[A, M[T]](el: M[T])`

Comment: @goral that is an error, not because `T` does not exist within the type parameter list, but because it does not exist within the constructor parameter list (see the first sentence in the quoted paragraph).

Comment: @goral In other words, `A` in `M[A]` shadows the other `A`. The scope of ends at `]`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it shadowing as compiler warns about this `scala> case class MC[A, A](el: A)
<console>:9: error: A is already defined as type A
       case class MC[A, A](el: A)
`

Comment: That is a completely different example. It doesn't have higher-kinded types in it. It's like comparing `{ val x = 1; { val x = 2  } }` and `{ val x = 1; val x = 2 }`.

Comment: So it's rather compiler constraint than semantic? I mean if `A` in `M[A]` wasn't ignored wouldn't be enough to type `case class MyContainer[M[A]](el: M[A])` ?

Comment: The language could have been designed that way, but it isn't.